# Is there a way to call nested array in Vue?

Tags: arrays, vue.js

I am really new to Vue JS. I was trying to print my nested object using `console.log` but it throws me an `undeifned` error.

**Array Image**

[image: Objects Description]

**View Code**

`<b-button variant="primary" v-on:click="dontknow();">Print</b-button>`

**Script**

```
methods:{
      dontknow(){
        console.log(this.allPlayerList.booker_id);
      },
 }
```

It displays me **undefined** when I use console.log(this.allPlayerList.booker_id). Can anyone please let me know what am I doing wrong? I want to get all the booker_id from allPlayerList.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`allPlayerList` obviously is an array of objects, which doesn't have itself a `booker_id` property, but contains objects which have it.

To print all the `booker_id` you need to loop over the array, and print it for every object, there are multiple ways of doing this, some of the common ways are:

```
this.allPlayerList.forEach(player => {
  console.log(player.booker_id);
});
```

Another way would be

```
console.log(this.allPlayerList.map(player => return player.booker_id));
```

The fist way will print every `booker_id` separately, while the second will print and array of all the `booker_id` items.

Comment: I tried it and returns me first object only when I use [0]. I need to print all the booker_id not only one.

Comment: @Yahoo I modified it to print all the `booker_id` items.

Comment: I missed out the forEach loop as it will contain multiple objects. Got it thank you. Your answer was helpful.